# Setting a Style using Binding in XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, coding-style

I need to set a `Style` of a given control according to some configuration value in Silverlight. I would like to have a possibility of choosing a `Style` for a control from two available styles (static resources). I was trying to do something like:

```xml
<TextBox Style="{Binding ABC}"/>
```

where

```
public string ABC
{
    get {return "{StaticResource MyStyle}";}
}
```

Unfortunately, that does not work.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. You need to be binding the `Style` property to a property of type `Style` though (not a string representing a static resource lookup).

You have two options for storage of the style and this will determine what the property looks like. Either put the style in the pages resources or in the App resources, and then you ABC property will look like one of the following:

```
// using page resources
public Style ABC
{
    get { return (Style) this.Resources["_myStyle"]; }
}

// using application resources
public Style ABC
{
    get { return (Style) App.Current.Resources["_myStyle"]; }
}
```

Where `_myStyle` is the value the style has for its `x:Key` property in the resource dictionary.